# Replacing Value From One Array to Another

Tags: php, arrays

Two arrays, one containing parameters and the other containing values, how I can I substitute the values in one from the vales of the other? Note that the number of values in either array will vary as will the key values but they have the commonality of the value $XX and the key [XX] (for example) between them to match.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => ID
    [2] => $ID
    [3] => Marque
    [4] => Marque
    [5] => $Marque
)

Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [Marque] => Make Name
)
```

What I am looking for is the first array with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => ID
    [2] => 2
    [3] => Marque
    [4] => Marque
    [5] => Make Name
)
```

I tried a loop within a loop but not sure how to match the value to the key and to recreate the repopulated array. All other values in the first array must be unchanged.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($newFields as $key=>$value) :
    foreach ($rowView as $newkey=>$newvalue) :
        if ($key == $newvalue) $key=$newvalue;
        $newArray[] = $newvalue;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Does the value of key 2 in the first array is string? (as the `'$ID'` of just `$ID`)

Comment: Good question. It is a string of $ID but can be anything, such as [ID] or whatever. I simply needed a way to differentiate it from the two previous values so made it appear as a variable with the $ preceding it.

Comment: I answered on both option - if there are not string but variable then the implementation is very elegant. String force you to use `array_map` of loop - both solution are one-liner

Comment: Does the value of key 2 in the first array is string?

Comment: @DonP in what way is my link a "bogus hyperlink"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$p = array(null, 'ID', '$ID', 'Marque', 'Marque', '$Marque');
$v = array('ID' => 2, 'Marque' => 'Make Name');

$r = array_map(
    function ($n) use ($v) {
        if (substr($n, 0, 1) == '$') {
            $k = substr($n, 1);
            return $v[$k];
        }
        return $n;
    },
    $p
);

var_dump($r);
```

Comment: Seems to work well so thank you! The arrays are both created dynamically and your code seems to be able to pick up and add the appropriate values exactly as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the first one array and match all the key of first one with the second array and assign if the first array's value is equal to second array's key value.
In that way, you could assign the values. It would not be recommended if the array size is huge. You can break the iteration once the value is assigned in the inner loop.

Comment: The arrays are all quite small and no problem there but I'm not all that familiar with arrays so once I figure out how to do what you suggested I'll give it a try.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array with replacements and see if the key exists in your array with array_search.
This way you are not at a risk that a key in the array has a $ but there is no replacement in the replacement array.

```
$arr = array(null, 'ID', '$ID', 'Marque', 'Marque', '$Marque');
$new = array('ID' => 2, 'Marque' => 'Make Name');

foreach($new as $key => $val){
    $search = array_search("$" . $key, $arr);
    if($search !== false){
        $arr[$search] = $val;
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/lP05J